# Interpretation of the Uncertainty Principle $||f(x)||_2^2 \le 4\pi ||x f(x)||_2 ||\omega\hat f(\omega)||_2$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

The Uncertainty Principle states that for any $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$
||f(x)||_2^2 \le 4\pi ||x f(x)||_2 ||\omega\hat f(\omega)||_2,
$$
and supposedly this means that a function $f$ and its Fourier Transform $\hat f$ can't both be concentrated in a small region. Well lets take a function $f$ with a small support, e.g. $f(x) = \chi_{(0,1)}$. Then $||f(x)||_2^2 = 1$ and $||x f(x)||_2 = 1/\sqrt 3$. So we have the following condition on $f(\omega)$:
$$
1 \le \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt 3} ||\omega\hat f(\omega)||_2,
$$
or
$$
\frac{\sqrt 3}{4 \pi} \le  ||\omega\hat f(\omega)||_2,
$$
I don't see how this implies that $\hat f$ must have large support. It seems that the support of $\hat f$ could be arbitrarily small as long as its magnitude is large enough to satisfy the bound?

Comment: But by making $\hat{f}$ large you might also make large $\|f\|_2^2$, by [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem). It is not like the last inequality you got is the only restriction for the choice of $\hat{f}$.

Comment: The interpretation can be read directly without getting into the shape of $f$ and its Fourier transform. The $L^2$ norms of $xf(x)$ and $x\hat{f}(x)$ are variances (a second moment). Fixing $\|f\|_2^2$ (or normalizing it to $1$), the inequality says that those two variances can't be both small.

Comment: @blueInk I'm not really understanding how this corresponds to my explicit example. How can it be explicitly shown that $\hat f$ cannot have finite support when $f = \chi_{(0,1)}$? I got as far as $\sqrt 3/(4\pi) \le ||\omega\hat f(\omega)||_2$ but that does not explicitly tell me that the support cannot be finite.

Comment: Your specific example is fixed. You can just compute $\hat{f}$. So, it is not an example of any shrinking. To do shrinking you will have to have a parametric example. Now, what you need to see is that the choice of $\|x\hat{f}(x)\|_2^2$ and the support of $\hat{f}$ is not free, because you have to preserve $\|f\|_2^2$ and they are linked.

Comment: @blueInk Ok I see you point now. Is it possible to write out such a parametric example to demonstrate explicitly what you are saying? I would like to understand precisely what is going on here and not just have rough idea of it.

Comment: You are unhappy with a Gaussian of arbitrary width?